# Delphi 10.2 IDE cannot see system processes from "Attach to Process" when debugging.- Yes I am "Running as administrator"

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have been using Delphi to write and debug Service Applications for years. I am aware that I must start Delphi with "Run as Administrator" to "Attach to" and debug Service Apps. Until recently this has always worked.
Recently Delphi has stopped listing “System Processes” in the “Running processes” list.  This circumstance is true for all installed versions of Delphi (10.2, XE8 & D2007). I am able to see system process from Visual Studio.
My Services are all 32bit Apps – though I don’t thing it matters, as I cannot see any system processes. 
Another potential clue is that Delphi only sees 32bit Apps running in the current (desktop) session, regardless of Target Platform settings in the project. 
I suspect that something may have changed in my OS (Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134 ) or Security Settings or something… I have tried disabling Virus SW (Webroot SecureAnywhere) nothing seems to make any difference.

Comment: Confirmed in Delphi 10.1 Berlin as well. Run as administrator, open a project, choose "Attach to Process", check on "Show System Processes", and no system processes get listed.

Comment: More info: Upon the advice of Embarcadero Support, I created another local admin user on my machine and logged in as such. Using that new administrative account, I am able to see/attach-to service apps. This doesn’t totally solve the problem because I would much rather not have to switch from my domain account every time I want to debug services. It does at least point out that this is likely an OS/User rights sort of issue.

Comment: Note: In C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin, my service wasn't listed the first time I looked.  I restarted C++ Builder as Administrator and the service now appears.  I'm not sure if it was because I opened it as Administrator, or if I just needed to restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a total solution it does serve as a work-around:

It appears that the “Attach to process” dialog will not show System processes until I actually attach to something. This behavior has been repeatable.

Start the Delphi IDE with “Run as administrator”. Choose “Attach to Process” from the “Run” menu. I notice that only the current Session Processes are visible.
I “Attach” to any item on the list, it does not matter which one. Then I choose “Detach from Program” from the “Run” menu.

Next, I choose “Attach to Process” again and now all of the processes, including System Processes, are visible.

Another interesting note, is that Checking or Unchecking the “Show system processes” makes no difference before or after the initial “Attach”.

System Processes will now be visible anytime I choose “Attach to Process” from the “Run” Menu as long as the IDE is running. If I close and restart the IDE with the “Run as administrator” option, the System Processes are hidden until I attach/detach again.